# Triangle above me, I rise to the top

Tags: riddle, word

> Triangle above me,
> I rise to the top.
> Triangle below me,
> I fall to the bottom.
> A thousand and above,
> If you click me, up and down.

What am I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Triangle above me,
> I rise to the top.
> Triangle below me,
> I fall to the bottom.

You are

> a question or answer's score on Stack Exchange. Upvoting makes it rise, downvoting makes it fall.

> A thousand and above,
> If you click me, up and down.

> @bobble points out that users with 1000 rep can click the score to see up and down totals.

Comment: Correct and congrats!